# Remove from set in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document as shown below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53329bjh3h4y4bc138b457e"),
    "cd" : 1395825662,
    "t" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52jhg4234jkhg1108b4567"),
            "ti" : "tagName1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("530c4234jffs0b0e088025"),
            "ti" : "tagname2"
        }
    ],
    "ud" : 1404966000
}
```

I want to remove tagName2 from the array t.

What is the efficient way to achieve  this?

What I tried is

```
  $mongoObj = new Mongodb\MongoQuery();
  $mongoObj->update(
            Constants::COLLECTIONNAME,
            $condition,
            array('$pull' => $data)
            );


$data = Array
         (
          [t.ti] => tagName2
         )
  $condition = Array
            (
             [_id] => MongoId Object
                 (
                   [$id] => 53329bjh3h4y4bc138b457e
                 )

            )
```

Do I need to use removeFromSet???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = Array
(
    [t] => Array
        (
            [ti] => tagname2
        )

)
```

I changed my $data array and it works for me...now $pull is working fine...

Thanks anyways....

Comment: This is not really an answer and you could have edited your own question. But really there was an answer posted several hours ago. Not hard to change JSON notation to PHP. You can even `json_decode`

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how to change the $data array with php syntax but he query is:

```
db.mycoll.update({},{$pull:{'t':{'t1':'tagname2'}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$collection->remove(array('t.ti' => 'tagname2'), true);
```

Reference [MongoCollection::remove](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php)

Comment: Document ID? Can you please explain your answer>

Comment: Collection `remove()` does exactly what it says. It removes the "document" matching from the collection. Not the array member from the document, which is what the OP was asking.

Comment: @NeilLunn I havent tested this. Yeah now I think what you say is true.